# Problem with incoerent local currency in contribution

Tags: drupal, contributions, ajax

I have a problem after upgrading to civicrm 5.4.1 from 4.7

When I confirm the record of a payment for a contribution the operation goes on forever and I have to exit the page although when I enter the contribution again the payment is registered.

When I look into the ajax requests with the Chrome DevTools I see that when the "record a new payment" popup is loaded it loads this script from the server (extract):

```
<span id='totalAmount'>
<select class="eight crm-select2 eight crm-form-select required" name="currency" id="currency">↵    
<option value="EUR" selected="selected">EUR (€)</option>
</select>&nbsp;<input size="6" maxlength="14" name="total_amount" type="text" value="1.00" id="total_amount" class="eight six crm-form-text required" />
</span>&nbsp; 
<span class="status">Balance Owed:&nbsp;€ 1,00</span>
```

Why is the value in total_amount 1.00 and the value showed in the Balance Owed 1,00?

When I confirm and register the payment the loading of the page goes on forever and when I look into the DevTools I see that this happens as the ajax request answers with an error:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. amount is not a valid amount: 1.00

Can anyone help with some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the decimal delimiter present at `civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1` is configured as a comma (`,`) instead of a default `.`.

Civi might not be handling this correctly when the record payment form is loaded. The value of the total amount defaults to `1.0` instead of considering the delimiter configured for your site, i.e, `1,0`. Either this might be a bug which needs to be fixed OR you can try using the default `.` in the above settings and check if it fixes for you.

Comment: Yes. Changing the decimal delimiter to . in civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1 resolves the problem. But in my country (Italy) we use comma, not point for decimal numbers, and the people using civicrm want's to insert amounts with a comma. How can I resolv both?

Comment: Check on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ by updating the setting to use comma. If you can replicate the behavior there too, raise a bug at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/new

Comment: Or if you are a developer, you can fix and contribute a patch to https://www.github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core repo

Comment: I have checked on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and it has the exact same problem when I set localization to use , instead of .